# The program hangs on the line system("prog .exe"); async doesn't work correctly

Tags: c++, windows, console, system, call

I got a problem with my code. When I try to open prog using system with some progs it works well, but with some for example, with Picasa 3 it stops and waits till Picasa closes. I write to command `"Picasa 3.exe"` cause it has space in the name, but if I rename it and use `start Picasa_3.exe` it works correctly. I tried to fix it using async but after 3 secs it only writes to the console `Command timed out.` and waits till Picasa closes, but it does `exit(0);`, but still waits till Picasa closes and only then closes.

My code

```
// Call the system command asynchronously
std::future<int> future = std::async(std::launch::async, executeSystemCommand, command);

// Wait for the response with a timeout of 3 seconds
if (future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(3)) == std::future_status::ready) {
    // Command executed within 3 seconds
    std::cout << "Command executed successfully." << std::endl;
}
else {
    // Command did not respond within 3 seconds
    std::cout << "Command timed out." << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

func executeSystemCommand

```
int executeSystemCommand(const std::string& command) {
    // Execute the system command
    std::system(command.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should provide an example of an executable it apparently "works" with.  The difference is clearly in the nature of the executable, not any difference in the behaviour of `system()` which you clearly misunderstand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system()` is a crude way of launching an executable since it has to launch a command shell which then launches your process.  The behaviour is very dependent upon the shell.

You could launch it in a separate thread, but a better solution would be to use one of the [_spawn variants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/spawn-wspawn-functions) or [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes) where you have far greater control over how the process runs.